# Database: inserting rows multi-query

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When I click on the submit button everything works except instead of putting the string's name inside the array, I get the name "array" in the row under column name for every row. I have been changing the code around all day and can't figure it out. Note my array has more than 130 strings inside of it.

You can put an unlimited amount of rows in a table, right?
Any suggestions on how to fix the name problem and increase my "limit 0, 30"?

Here's my code:

was:

```
$array = ("","","");
$random = $array;
shuffle($random);
```

Now:

```
$array = ("","","");
```

And still doesn't work. I also tried experimenting with mysqli_stmt_send_long_data couldn't get it to work either.

```
<?php
include ('login-home.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli("", "", "", "");
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_error . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table(id, name) VALUES (id, '".$array."')")) {
    echo "Multi-INSERT failed: (" . $mysqli->error . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
/* Prepared statement, stage 2: bind and execute */
$id = 1;
if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", $id)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->error . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->error . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

for ($id; $id = $id+1; $id++) {
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->error . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }
}

$stmt->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably get array to insert because the variable is an array..

try to

```
echo $array; /// the output will be array
```

So if you want to get the value of the array to insert into db
you must first convert them to strings using concatenation and foreach loop or any php functions
that will do that. like explode them implode and etc.

these will convert

```
$array = ("ar1","ar2","ar3");
```

to

```
$array = "ar1,ar2,ar3";
```

Comment: Thanks ill work on that it'll take awhile but tried it on one and it worked thanks